# Getting the minimum value of a column in a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find the minimum value in a 2D array(Java).

I'm trying to use a for loop. My aim is to create a program that gets the saddle point of a matrix but I'm going step-by-step. I have figured out how to find the max value in a row of a 2D array. Then I want to find the min value IN the same column as the max value.

Here is my code:

```
class Matrix_1 {
   int[][] A;
   int a;
   int b;
   int max;
   int min;
   int i;
   int d;

   Matrix_1() {
      super();
   }

   public int[][] createMatrix(int a, int b) {
      Scanner inputm = new Scanner(System.in);
      A = new int[a][b];
      System.out.println("Enter elements for matrix A : ");
      for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("Enter numbers for " + i + "th row");
         for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {
            A[i][j] = inputm.nextInt();

         }

      }
      return A;
   }

   public int[][] displayMatrix() {
      System.out.println("Matrix A: ");

      for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
         System.out.println();
         for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(A[i][j] + " ");
         }
      }

      return A;
   }

   public int getMax(int c) {
      max = 0;
      a = c;

      for (i = 0; i < A[a].length; i++) {

         while (A[a][i] > max) {
            max = A[a][i];
         }
      }

      i = d;
      System.out.println(i);
      System.out.println("max = " + max);
      return max;
   }

   public int getMin() {
      max = min;
      a = 0;

      for (int j = 0; j < A[a].length; j++) {
         while (A[i][j] < min) {
            min = A[j][d];
         }
      }

      System.out.println("min in row " + a + "from max number" + max + " = "
            + min);
      return min;
   }
}
```

Comment: The first two methods work fine.

Comment: @deporter it is but at least I've attempted it myself. I just want some help.

Comment: Try changing max = min in getMin() to min = max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these methods to list the maximum/minimum of every row and column:

```
public void getMaximumOfEveryColumn ()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ )
    {
        max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for ( int j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )
            if ( A [ j ] [ i ] > max )
                max = A [ j ] [ i ];
        System.out.println( "Maximum of column " + i + " = " + max );
    }
}

public void getMinimumOfEveryColumn ()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ )
    {
        min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for ( int j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )
            if ( A [ j ] [ i ] < min )
                min = A [ j ] [ i ];
        System.out.println( "Minimum of column " + i + " = " + min );
    }
}
public void getMaximumOfEveryRow ()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ )
    {
        max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for ( int j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )
            if ( A [ i ] [ j ] > max )
                max = A [ i ] [ j ];
        System.out.println( "Maximum of row " + i + " = " + max );
    }
}

public void getMinimumOfEveryRow ()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ )
    {
        min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for ( int j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )
            if ( A [ i ] [ j ] < min )
                min = A [ i ] [ j ];
        System.out.println( "Minimum of row " + i + " = " + min );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I get bits of the code but do you mind explaining it please.

Comment: The above solution wont work for non square matrix. Can u please see my answer in down and correct it.

Answer (score 2):

This gets the minimun value on the same row as maximum

```
public int minOnMaxRow(){

   int max = Integer.Min_Value();
   int min;

   for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
       for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++){
           if (A[i][j] > max){
              max = A[i][j];
              min = Integer.Max_Value();
              for(k= 0; k < A[i].length; k++){
                 if (A[i][k] < min){
                    min = A[i][k]
                  }
              }
           }
        }
     }
     return min;
 }
```

Comment: What does Integer.Min_Value() do?

Comment: It is a static method in the Integer class that returns the smallest value a integer can adopt, Max_Value does the opposit

Answer (score 0):

Minimum and maximum value for a column in matrix :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Max_Min_Row_Col {

    static int col;
    static int row;
    static int[][] trans_arr = new int[col][row];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        row = m;
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        col = n;
        int[][] arr = new int[row][col];

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        int i_old = 0;
        int m_old = arr[i_old].length;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_old; i++) {
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
                if (arr[j][i] < min)
                    min = arr[j][i];
            System.out.println("Minimum of column " + i + " = " + min);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m_old; i++) {
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
                if (arr[j][i] > max)
                    max = arr[j][i];
            System.out.println("Maximum of column " + i + " = " + max);
        }
    }

}
```